# Number of sub graphs of a complete graph

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a complete graph with $m$ edges and $n$ vertices, and $P(G)$ be the set of all possible sub graphs of $G$. Then the number of elements in $P(G)$, i.e., $|P(G)|=2^n+\binom m1+\binom m2+...+\binom mm.$ I believe that this formula is true. Your valuable comments are most welcome, please.

Comment: $m=n=3$, formula gives $15$, I count $18$ subgraphs.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A006896

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, gete?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thanks for your point. The formula would really need a modification. Anybody comes with better formulations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  In that case(i.e., $m=n=3$), i seem to have missed to count those three sub graphs with one isolated vertex in each.

Comment: "The formula would really need a modification. Anybody comes with better formulations would be highly appreciated." What about the formula at the OEIS site?

Comment: Gerry Myerson, That seems really great, but i could see only out puts clearly but not Mathematical formulations, may be my system is not supporting.

Comment: You can't see the formula, a(n) = 1 + C(n, 1) + C(n, 2)*2 + C(n, 3)*2^3 + C(n, 4)*2^6 + ... + C(n, n)*2^(n*(n-1)/2) ? That's $$a(n)=1+{\binom n 1}+2{\binom n 2}+2^3{\binom n 3}+\cdots+2^{n(n-1)/2}{\binom n n}$$

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, a correct formula seems to be $$\sum_{k=0}^na_k{\binom n k}$$ where $a_k=2^{\binom k 2}=2^{k(k-1)/2}$.

Comment: If someone wants to know how to interpret this formula, one quora [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-determine-the-number-of-sub-graphs-of-a-complete-graph/answer/Matt-Correia-1) is very helpful.